# Starting multiple projects when debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications, nservicebus

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a web application and a console application (actually a service using NServiceBus, but it runs locally as a console application) that I want to both startup when I hit Debug.

Right now I have the Web Application set as the startup application and it opens in a browser, then I right click on my Service and go to Debug -> Start new instance.  This works fine, but I would rather not do it manually because I sometimes forget and need the Service running to handle messages from the website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can start multiple projects by choosing multiple projects to start and the order by right clicking on the solution node on the solution explorer and selecting Properties from the menu. Select the radio button for "Multiple startup projects" and choose the action as Start for the required projects.

Comment: That's where it is hidden.  Thanks!  I can't mark this as correct yet because it's too soon, but I'll be back to do that shortly.

Comment: This is just one of those things that you want to stick on your screen! :-)